# SQL subquery to find duplicates

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008

this question is related to mine of just a minute ago. I'm looking for duplicate records in one table. I'm looking for matching fields "Symbol," and "TradeDate." I have a unique ID field for the table. My logic is: return the records with an ID field that is not the minimum ID value that have a count > 1 for that symbol and date combination. Here's what I've got... sql server doesn't complain about it until I run it, then it says my subquery is returning more than one value:

```
SELECT Symbol , ID FROM tblDailyPricingAndVol 
     WHERE (SELECT Count(TradeDate) FROM tblDailyPricingAndVol AS T2 
          WHERE T2.Symbol = Symbol AND T2.TradeDate = TradeDate GROUP BY Symbol) > 1 
          AND ID <> (SELECT MIN(ID) FROM tblDailyPricingAndVol AS T3 
               WHERE T3.Symbol = Symbol AND T3.TradeDate = TradeDate
          GROUP BY Symbol)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
;WITH x AS
(
  SELECT ID, TradeDate, Symbol, 
    rn = ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY TradeDate, Symbol ORDER BY ID)
    FROM dbo.tblDailyPricingAndVol
)
SELECT ID, TradeDate, Symbol, rn
FROM x WHERE rn > 1
ORDER BY TradeDate, Symbol;
```

If your next question is going to be "now I want to remove the duplicates" let me save you some trouble, as it's a simple change:

```
;WITH x AS
(
  SELECT ID, rn = ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY TradeDate, Symbol ORDER BY ID)
    FROM dbo.tblDailyPricingAndVol
)
DELETE x WHERE rn > 1;
```

Comment: Thanks. I edited my logic description based on your post... I do want to return all BUT the minimum ID. When I get this working I'll change it to a delete statement. Is there a way to do this with a simple select/ subquery? (not familiar with PARTITION). I'm wondering how either of my subqueries can return more than one value, with each being an aggregate function.

Comment: Looks like I pre-empted you. PS In the subqueries you have `GROUP BY Symbol` only.

Comment: I just caught that... I changed to "GROUP BY Symbol, TradeDate" to no avail.

Comment: Did the query I provide yield the correct answer? Sorry, but since 2005 introduced these windowing functions I can't think in terms of old-school subqueries. It's like looking around for leaded gasoline or Windows 95 install disks.

Comment: Worked quite well. Nice.. so PARTITION does just what the name implies, and each subset is numbered independent of the id field?

Comment: Yes, if you just do a select from the CTE without the where clause, you will see all the row_number values that have been attached to each row. They start over for each new TradeDate, Symbol combination.